# What is the remnant of Edom?

Tags: hebrew, amos

Amos states:

> *“In that day I will raise up
>       the booth of David that is fallen
>   and repair its breaches,
>       and raise up its ruins
>       and rebuild it as in the days of old, that they may possess the remnant of Edom
>       and all the nations who are called by my name,”
>       declares the Lord who does this. (Amos 9:11-12 ESV)*

Is the remnant of Edom referring to the land of Edom or to the people, or both?

Is there an connection between this prophecy in Amos and the one given by Balaam?

> *Edom shall be dispossessed;
>       Seir also, his enemies, shall be dispossessed.
>       Israel is doing valiantly.
>   19 And one from Jacob shall exercise dominion
>       and destroy the survivors of cities!” (Numbers 24:18-19 ESV)*

What is the remnant of Edom?

Comment: Residue (like a grain of sand) of A-dam (un-domesticated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Septuagint identifies the remnant of Edom as the "remnant of men", which, in context, appears to be the remnant of Israel:

*"In that day I will raise up the tabernacle of David that is fallen, and will rebuild the ruins of it, and will set up the parts thereof that have been broken down, and will build it up as in the ancient days: that the remnant of men, and all the Gentiles upon whom my name is called, may earnestly seek me, saith the Lord who does all these things." -- Amos 9:11-12 LXX*

James appears to be quoting from the Septuagint in the Acts 15 fulfillment:

*"That the residue of men might seek after the Lord, and all the Gentiles, upon whom my name is called, saith the Lord, who doeth all these things." -- Acts 15:17 KJV*

The Amos prophecy is similar to this Isaiah prophecy:

*"And he said to me, It is a great thing for thee to be called my servant, to establish the tribes of Jacob, and to recover the dispersion of Israel: behold, I have given thee for the covenant of a race, for a light of the Gentiles, that thou shouldest be for salvation to the end of the earth." -- Isa 49:6 LXX*

The Hebrew text of Isaiah 49:6 calls the "dispersion of Israel" the "preserved of Israel".

:)

Comment: I think there is merit in considering the passage in the LXX especially in terms of how it was understood in the second Temple period. The LXX (and Acts) renders סֻכַּ֥ת (booth) as σκηνὴν (tent/tabernacle). The Greek lacks a corresponding word to clearly record what Amos prophesied: that the LORD would raise up David’s booth (presumably at the time of the Feast of Booths). Since אֱדוֹם֙ (Edom) is not consistently rendered in the LXX, the use of ἀνθρώπων in Amos (not Εδωμ as in Genesis 36:21) suggests the translator includes an element of interpretation.

Comment: As you note the NT passage is following the LXX. If that is the case the LXX/NT interpretation would be accurate (that is ἀνθρώπων is the meaning). Yet the original prophecy was Εδωμ. So why would the LXX translator see ἀνθρώπων and not Εδωμ as the correct meaning? The remnant of Israel makes sense for James in Acts. Is that true for the LXX +/-200 years before Christ?

Comment: The Hebrew manuscript of a version of the LXX was found with the Dead Sea Scrolls:

" . . . there was indeed a Hebrew text-type on which the Septuagint-translation was based and which differed substantially from the received MT." [Menachem Cohen, "The Idea of the Sanctity of the Biblical Text." 1979]

Comment: The New Testament has shown that both the LXX and Masoretic are God's Word; and the Dead Sea sect had access to those, and more:

    "The people of Qumran (apparently the Essene sect) had access to several text-types of the Scriptural text: In essence, all Hebrew text-types represented by the MT as well as those behind the Septuagint and the Samaritan text, served the sect in its study and worship." [Menachem Cohen, "The Idea of the Sanctity of the Biblical Text." 1979]

Answer (score -1):

He's talking about the true Hebrew Israelites scattered all over the world most thru slavery. 12 tribes, he's going to bring them back together to Africa, Isolele.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX. Thanks for your excellent contribution. Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This needs to orthography repair and some evidence and references.  As it sites it reads only like a comment.